# Posty_API error: There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postfix-mta, gemfile, mail-server

I'm trying to install posty_API on my mailserver (uses MySQL and Postfix) and it shows error on command `rake db:migrate`

> There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.

Gemfile:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rack', '~> 1.5.2'
gem 'rake', '~> 10.3.2'
gem 'grape', '~> 0.7.0'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 3.2.22',:require => 'active_record'
gem 'json'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'schema_plus', '~> 1.5.1'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rack-test',:require => 'rack/test'
  gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'racksh'
  gem 'rubocop'
end

group :mysql, optional: true do
  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.16'
end

group :postgresql, optional: true do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
  gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
end
```

In addition, when i tried to run it via `bundle install` i saw

> Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 45 gems now installed. Gems
>   in the group db were not installed.

I will be glad to any help. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: types error: rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'mysql socket path (/var/mysql/mysql.sock)' (2)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: so problem is in mysql server

Comment: Yes, i see. Can it be caused by missing or renamed MySQL folder?

Answer (score 0):

I just added host of remote SQL server, created test database, made `rake db:migrate`, then moved tables to old database and made `rake db:migrate` once more time.